# How to set the priority to thread in LISP?

Tags: multithreading, common-lisp

```
(defvar firstnumber)
(defvar secondnumber)
(defvar length1)
(defvar mulb)
(defvar var1)
(defvar num1)
(defvar num2)
(defvar addition)
(defvar subs)
(defvar muls)
(defvar divs)

(defun acceptnumber()
    (write-line "Enter the first number:")
    (force-output t)
    (setf firstnumber(read))
    (write-line "Enter the second number:")
    (force-output t)
    (setf secondnumber(read))
    (setf length1(integer-length secondnumber))
)

(defun add(num1 num2)
    (setf addition(+ num1 num2))
    (write-line "Addition of two numbers:")
    (write addition)
    (write-line " " )
)

(defun sub(num1 num2)
    (setf subs(- num1 num2))
    (write-line "Substraction of two numbers:")
    (write subs)
    (write-line " ")

)
(defun mul(num1 num2)
    (setf muls(* num1 num2))
    (write-line "Multiplication of two numbers:")
    (write muls)
    (write-line " ")
)
(defun div(num1 num2)
    (setf divs(/ num1 num2))
    (write-line "Division of two numbers:")
    (write divs)
    (write-line " ")
)

(defun binarymul(num1 num2)

    (setf mulb 0)

    (
        loop for i from 1 to length1 do 
        (
            if(= 1 (logand num2 1))
            (setf mulb(+ mulb num1))
        )

    (setf num2(ash num2 -1))    
    (setf num1(ash num1 1))

    )
(write-line "Binary Multiplication ::")
(write mulb)
(write-line " ")
(write-line "In binary form::")
(setf var1(format nil "~B" mulb ))
(write-line var1)
)





(acceptnumber)
(sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(binarymul firstnumber secondnumber)))
(sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(add firstnumber secondnumber)))
(sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(sub firstnumber secondnumber)))
(sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(mul firstnumber secondnumber)))
(sb-thread:make-thread(lambda()(div firstnumber secondnumber)))
```

I started learning with LISP concurrent programming. I wrote a simple calculation program with sb-thread. Now i want to set the priority for each thread. Ex like set priority higher ti binarymul function etc.
Can I set  priority of sb-thread ? If yes How?

Answer (score 0):

SBCL's manual says (emphasis added):

> #### [12 Threading](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Threading)
>
> SBCL supports a fairly low-level threading interface that maps onto
>   the host operating system’s concept of threads or lightweight
>   processes. This means that threads may take advantage of hardware
>   multiprocessing on machines that have more than one CPU, but **it does
>   not allow Lisp control of the scheduler.** This is found in the
>   SB-THREAD package.

I *think* that thread priority would typically require some access to the scheduler, so you won't have the ability to set thread priority with SBCL.